# Embeddable Enterprise Collaboration (Microblogging) Engine

Tags: collaboration, microblogging

**Short Version (tl;dr):**

Is there an open source or commercial engine that provides embeddable collaboration and microblogging functionality?

**Long Version:**

I am creating a niche application that has need of this functionality and do not want to reinvent the wheel.  The following are must have requirements:

- Data API only.  My application is SaaS, and I want to build the functionality around the data.  This eliminates most of the offerings out there (facebook, salesforce chatter, yammer, present.ly, teambox)
- Does not require use of a built-in front end.  I really just want an engine that will take care of the storage and events, and gives me a means of querying.  Requiring the use of a specific front end renders it useless for embedding into my app.  This eliminates everything else I have found (status.net, Yonkly, Jaiku)
- Beyond standard updates and replies, can handle custom events.  For example, if I were embedding this into an logistics application, I could have the engine handle events like "shipped", "received", and "cancelled".

Beyond this, there are several nice to have features that a framework would have:

- Should not require a specific platform or server technology to run (i.e. something like a RESTful API would be nice)
- Should be message based so that commands that affect its state can come from any source
- Should encapsulate its own storage so that external resources are not necessary (i.e. no database needed)
- Should have pluggable extendable UI components/widgets for web, mobile, and desktop clients
- Should have search and retrieval APIs available for many languages/platforms

It seems that someone out there should have this already, or at least be in progress with it.  Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If this does not exist, I would be willing to start and lead an OSS project to create it.

Comment: contact me at mark@300.mg...our solution seems similar to what you request. And if not, we might join you with your OSS initiative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody had any answers and continued research did not find anything, I created a solution on my own called [Collabinate](http://www.collabinate.com).  Updates can be found on [Twitter](http://twitter.com/collabinate), and the project itself is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Collabinate/Collabinate).